# C++: Pass array created in the function call line

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I achieve a result like somebody would expect it according to the following code example:

```
// assuming: void myFunction( int* arr );

myFunction( [ 123, 456, 789 ] );

// as syntactical sugar for...

int values[] = { 123, 456, 789 };
myFunction( values );
```

The syntax I thought would work spit out a compile error.

- How can I define an argument array directly in the line where the function is called?

Comment: error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before 'constant'

Comment: bad idea doing this, `myFunction` has no way of knowing the size of the passed in array. Almost always better off using something like `vector`

Comment: No, using vector would be a bad choice in my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve that syntactic sugar with C++ code, not in C++03. The only place where braces are allowed, referring to elements of an array, is in initializing a named array:

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Nowhere else. You can however achieve a similar effect with Boost.Assign:

```
void f(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
}

// ...
f(boost::assign::list_of(123)(456)(789));
```

Comment: Removed the "class with proper constructor" idea. Bad idea, don't listen to the silly guy who wrote it.

Answer (score 7):

If you were using C (C99, specifically), you could have used a compound literal here:

```
myFunction( (int []) {123, 456, 789} );
```

But the are not part of C++ (your compiler may still support them, though). In C++0x, you could use an initializer list, but they don't decay to pointers (not that using raw pointers is a good idea to begin with).

Although if you change the signature of myFunction to `void myFunction( const int* arr )`, you would be able to do the contrived call

```
myFunction( std::initializer_list<int>({123, 456, 789}).begin() );
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like what you are looking for is proposed as part of the [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists) standard.
  I don't believe there is a way to do it otherwise (currently).

```
void function_name(std::initializer_list<float> list);

function_name({1.0f, -3.45f, -0.4f});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you have to use two things:

1. use `std::vector` (or any other C++ STL class)
2. use **-std=c++0x** compilation switch (or anything else for you compiler to use the c++0x standard).